# No Output for Python Script Executed via Cron Job

Tags: python-2.7, centos, cron

Relatively new to running cron jobs in Centos6, I can't seem to get this Python script to execute properly. I would like this script to execute and then email me the output. I have been receiving emails, but they're empty.

So far, in Crontab I've tried entering:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /home/local/MYCOMPANY/purrone/MyPythonScripts_Dev1 && /usr/bin/python ParserScript_CampusInsiders.py  > /var/log/cron`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log 2>&1 ; mailx -s "Feedparser Output" my@email.com
```

and

```
*/10 * * * * /home/local/MYCOMPANY/purrone/MyPythonScripts_Dev1/ParserScript_CampusInsiders.py > /var/log/cron`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log 2>&1 ; mailx -s "Feedparser Output" my@email.com
```

I have run `chmod +x` on the python script to make the script executable and the Python script has `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the header. What am I doing wrong here?

The other problem might be that I shouldn't be using the log file? All I see at /var/log/cron when I open with cat cron is entires like this, for example (no actual output from the script):

```
Jul 23 13:20:01 ent-mocdvsmg01 CROND[24681]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 13:20:01 ent-mocdvsmg01 CROND[24684]: (MYJOB\purrone) CMD (/home/local/MYCOMPANY/purrone/MyPythonScripts_Dev1/ParserScript_CampusInsiders.py > /var/log/cron`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log 2>&1 ; mailx -s "Feedparser Output" my@email.com)
```

Comment: Is that cron log file working? You aren't sending any output to `mailx` where is it supposed to be getting the content of your email from?

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing that there's no output from the script in the log file at `/var/log/cron` when I opened cron with `cat cron` there's just the actual cron job. Inserting what I'm seeing in log to my post above...

Comment: Does the correct `/var/log/cronXXXXX-cron.log` file get created at least? Even if it then empty?

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like cronxxxxx-cron.log. All I'm seeing that directory that looks related to cron jobs is: chrony, cron, cron-20150719. Nothing related to my script in those files.

Comment: You are looking in `/var/log/` directly and not `/var/log/cron/` right? If you don't see the files then that shell command isn't being run at all. (And I wouldn't expect you to get any mail either.)

Comment: Does using `$(...)` instead of backticks help any? Can you run `env -i sh -xc '/home/local/MYCOMPANY/purrone/MyPythonScripts_Dev1/ParserScript_CampusInsiders.py > /var/log/cron\`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S\`-cron.log 2>&1'` correctly? Does it create the log file?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking in /var/log directly

Comment: Yes! Now I can see: `cron2015-07-23-15:33:35-cron.log`

Comment: And does it have the contents you expect when you run it like that?

Comment: Yes it does! Does that mean I can take this line and insert it into Crontab? env -i sh -xc '/home/local/MYCOMPANY/purrone/MyPythonScripts_Dev1/ParserScript_CampusInsiders.‌​py > /var/log/cron`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log 2>&1'

Comment: I doubt that would help. That `env` command pattern is one of the debugging steps for non-working cron commands (in the [tag:crontab] info wiki) though. So your command itself works in the cron environment but something else is going on that is keeping it from working correctly in cron itself. Wait... is that per-user crontab trying to write to `/var/log`? That's not going to work. Try some other directory and/or stop that and just pipe to `mailx`.

Comment: Are you saying I could just skip sending the output to /var/log or any other log directory and instead just put the output in an email?

Comment: You seemed to want the output in an email in the first place. If that's the case then yes, drop the redirection to the file entirely and instead just pipe it to `mailx` (probably with standard error too `2>&1). Otherwise, if you do want a log file, and that is a per-user crontab, then use a directory that your user can create files in (i.e. not `/var/log`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to omit the redirect `>` and instead edit the Crontab thusly:

```
*/15 * * * * /home/local/COMPANY/malvin/SilverChalice_CampusInsiders/SilverChalice_Parser.py | tee /home/local/COMPANY/malvin/SilverChalice_CampusInsiders`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log | mailx -s "SilverChalice CampusInsiders" my@email.com
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing going into your `mailx` input; it expects the message on *stdin*. Try running it outside of crontab as a test until it sends a valid email. You could test with:

```
% echo hello |mailx -s test my@email.com
```

Note that cron can email you the output of its run. You just need to add a line to the top of `crontab` like:

```
MAILTO = you@email.com
```

Comment: I do get "test" in the subject of the email, should I also be getting "hello" as well?

Comment: No "test" is just the subject. "hello" is the whole message body. It’s just like `cat full-message-body.txt | mailx ...` or `mailx ... < full-message-body`. So instead of `cat` you want your python script sending its `stdout` into `mailx`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really clear on what I need to do differently. Right now in crontab I've got the following: `MAILTO = my@email.com

*/10 * * * * /home/local/mycompany/chris/SilverChalice_CampusInsiders/SilverChalice_CampusInsiders.py > `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log 2>&1; mailx -s "SilverChalice Feedparser" my@email.com`